# How to create dynamic class instances from multiple class modules in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, class, object

I have several class modules (let's assume classA, classB and so on) created for different purposes. From the main file, I want to create instance dynamically from each class

Rather than creating instance one by one like below, I want to create them dynamically through a loop. The below "**classname**" value cannot be replaced by a variable (**$classname**) as I checked. Any proper method to get this done?

```
[<classname>]$instance = [<classname>]::new()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`-as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.2) or simply cast [`[type]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-7.0) to instantiate them, for example:

```
class A {
    $prop = 'classA' 
}
class B {
    $prop = 'classB' 
}
class C {
    $prop = 'classC' 
}

foreach ($i in 'A', 'B', 'C') {
    ($i -as [type])::new() # with `-as`
    ([type] $i)::new()     # casting
}
```

Assuming you will be instantiating many times using this method, it will be preferable to cache the types in different variables (using `class A` as example):

```
$classA = 'A' -as [type]
0..10 | ForEach-Object {
    $classA::new()
}
```

Alternatively, personally wouldn't recommend this method, but you can use [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7.3):

```
foreach ($i in 'A', 'B', 'C') {
    New-Object $i
}
```

Comment: `New-Object` gives the most clear error message though, if the type doesn't exist.